# How to parse time given an hours

Tags: ruby

I have an integer which denotes an hours. How can I create Time from it? Something like:

```
Time.parse(3) => 3:00
Time.parse(21) => 21:00
```

Comment: And what should be the date?

Comment: `Time` abstracts both date and time (including time zones). So there must be a date (today, 1970-01-01, 0001-01-01, etc.).

Comment: @AlanCoromano when asking for assistance you will catch more flies with honey than vinegar. Abrasive comments generally dissuade constructive answers.

Comment: @RossMC's answer uses today as date, so what exactly should I learn from it?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I'm not asking you for advice. I'll catch one anyway.

Comment: @cremno, open your eyes.

Comment: I only see a bad question and rude comments (I also saw the now deleted one where you called somebody else crazy because they didn't understand your bad question). The answer involves a date which means I'm correct. Otherwise please explain where and why I'm not. I'd like to know.

Comment: @AlanCoromano since you have felt the need to be so abrasive lets get something else straight. The accepted answer is a String not a time if that's all you wanted then there are a million and 1 solutions to this problem. If you wanted a True Time Object as specified then cremno is correct and it will come with a Date attached.

Comment: @cremno, where do you see "uses today as date" in RossMc's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the hour with `Time#strptime`

```
hour = 4
Time.strptime("#{hour}", "%H")
 => 2015-11-02 04:00:00 +0000
```

And then parse with `Time#strftime` if you're interested in the formatting.

```
Time.strptime("#{hour}", "%H").strftime("%H:%M")
=> "04:00"
```